# Why functions on Context Item selected are not called

Tags: java, android, fragment, contextmenu

I am working with tab layout. I have defined some functions in my fragment class but on function calling from context Item selected method , it is giving error  "Method is not created."
I also write code inside the onACtivity method but did not work.
please help!

Java Code

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment 
{
    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    Button buttonstartEndDialog;
    Button buttonCancelAlarm;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt2;


    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    final static int RQS_2 = 2;
     int FIRST_OPTION = 1;
     int SECOND_OPTION = 2;
     int Third_OPTION = 3;
     int Fourth_OPTION = 4;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.set_time,container,false);
        return v;}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);
    textAlarmPrompt2 = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt2);

    buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog(false);
            //buttonstartSetDialog.setClickable(false);
            //buttonstartSetDialog.setClickable(false);
            //buttonCancelAlarm.setClickable(true);

        }


            private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                        getActivity(), 
                        onTimeSetListener, 
                        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                        is24r);

                timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

                timePickerDialog.show();
            }

            OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
            = new OnTimeSetListener(){

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    }

                    setAlarm(calSet);

                }};

            private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){


                textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                        "\n\n***\n"
                        + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                        + "***\n");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }

            private void cancelAlarm(){


                textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                        "\n\n***\n"
                        + "Alarm Cancelled! \n"
                        + "***\n");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

            }});

    //Registering Start Time Button for context menu

    registerForContextMenu(buttonstartSetDialog);
    buttonstartSetDialog.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View arg1,
                ContextMenuInfo arg2) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose");
            menu.add(0, FIRST_OPTION, 0, "Edit");
            menu.add(0, SECOND_OPTION, 0, "Delete");

        }
    });



    /********* Opening Time picker dialog from end time button *********/

    buttonstartEndDialog = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.startEndDialog);

    buttonstartEndDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            textAlarmPrompt2.setText("");
            openTimePickerDialog2(false);
            //buttonstartSetDialog.setClickable(false);
            //buttonstartEndDialog.setClickable(false);
            //buttonCancelAlarm.setClickable(true);

        }

            private void openTimePickerDialog2(boolean is24r){
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                        getActivity(), 
                        onTimeSetListener2, 
                        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                        is24r);

                timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

                timePickerDialog.show();
            }

            OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener2
            = new OnTimeSetListener(){

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                    }

                    setAlarm2(calSet);

                }};

            private void setAlarm2(Calendar targetCal){

                textAlarmPrompt2.setText(
                        "\n\n***\n"
                        + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                        + "***\n");

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReciever_for_Normal.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), RQS_2, intent2, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
        //buttonstartSetDialog.setClickable(false);
                //buttonCancelAlarm.setEnabled(false);
            }
            private void cancelAlarm2(){

                textAlarmPrompt2.setText(
                        "\n\n***\n"
                        + "Alarm Cancelled! \n"
                        + "***\n");

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReciever_for_Normal.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), RQS_2, intent2, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent2);

            }});

    registerForContextMenu(buttonstartEndDialog);
    buttonstartEndDialog.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose");
                menu.add(0, Third_OPTION, 0, "Edit");
                menu.add(0, Fourth_OPTION, 0, "Delete");


            }});


}
 @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if(itemId == FIRST_OPTION){
        openTimePickerDialog(false);    
        return true;

        }
        else if(itemId == SECOND_OPTION){

            cancelAlarm();
            return true;

        }
        else if(itemId == Third_OPTION){
            openTimePickerDialog2(false);   
            return true;

            }
            else if(itemId == Fourth_OPTION){

                cancelAlarm2();
                return true;

            }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }



}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error "Method is not created"? Which line?

Comment: @findusl
see my updated code file.
I am facing error while trying to calling all function in oncontext item clicked method at last

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The `cancelAlarm()` is defined in the wrong place, as it's inside the `OnClickListener` and the other methods can't see it.

Consider it putting at the same level as the other methods. Also this way you won't be able to reach some variables defined inside onActivityCreated, you should create field variables for them.

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment 
{
    ...

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
        @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

   @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View arg1, ContextMenuInfo arg2) {});

   private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){...}

   OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener(){...};

   private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){...}

   private void cancelAlarm(){...}
}
```

Comment: Now see i have defined all methods but still facing error

Comment: The problem is that your cancelAlarm is inside the OnClickListener. Put it in the original class to be able to call it from the other methods.

Comment: But the error is not only regarding cancelalarm() .It's pointing to all methods calling in on context item clicked methods

Comment: Because you instantiated an OnClickListener, and implemented methods in that class. you should move out all the methods you need. I also suggest to learn more about Object Oriented programming to understand basic concepts.

Comment: I've updated my answer, check the level of the methods

Comment: it worked !
Thanks alot :)
Yeah you are right!
I just starting implementation of Object Oriented programming but i will learn it soon.